# How to convert PowerPoint, PDF, and Word files to different slides like SlideShare?

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend, slideshow

I would like to be able to display PowerPoint slides.
How should I implement this?

How did a website like Slideshare actually implement this?

When you upload a PowerPoint, Word, or PDF file, each page is displayed as a slide, each of which is a div and contains the image tag of that page with different qualities.

How can I do this with the front-end and back-end? (the back-end is with PHP).
Is there a library for it?

Answer (score 0):

For **Back-end** you can use these libraries by [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice)

- [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) for handling word documents.
- [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation) for handling presentation documents.